# Distorted Image texture as background

Tags: texturing, node-editor, 3d-view, image, scale

This is the background image that i want to use

[image]

But when i open it into the world panel, the preview and the rendered background are different. I've tried several options to scale it: adding mapping, image texture and texture coordinate nodes, scaling in the mapping node or in the texture panel, also tried to resize the image... and nothing works. I don't know how to put the whole image as background.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I've tried window texture coordinates, but now the background is pixeled. Any idea?

[image]

How it's seen through the camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple setups, you can use the Import Images as Planes addon and just place and scale the image plane as you need relative to camera as if it is a matte painting background object. You can even set it up to emit if you want.

Answer (score 2):

For normal images like these, you can use the Windows Texture Coordinates:

[image: Node Tree]

Comment: I just tried what you told me before, and the display is correct. The only problem now is that the rendered background has really big pixels. Any idea? I'm gonna add the new pic above explaining this

Comment: @Sanni Are you viewing that from a camera? if not, try adding a camera and render. Report back, I suspect this may be a blender bug.

Comment: I'm viewing that in real time rendering, but it's more or less the same that through the camera. I'll post the pic above

Comment: @Sanni It is happening for me as well. It is definitely a bug. Should I report or will you?

Comment: @Sanni I have a way to reproduce the bug, post in the report with you, may it will help them fix it.
1. Open an empty scene with no camera.
2. Add texture coordinates node to the world.
3. View one of the outputs of the texture coordinates node, everything should be working fine.
4. Add a camera while in rendering mode.
5. Make camera the active scene camera using `ctrl + 0`.
6. Pan outside of camera view.
7. All texture coordinates are now pixelated.

Comment: ok, i'll check it later